# Why doesn't Usopp create great weapons for himself?

Tags: one-piece

Usopp is the sniper of the Straw Hat Pirates and also a craftsman who created weapons like his fake 5 ton hammer. He also created a sort of a "magic" weapon, Clima Tact that he made for Nami.

I wonder why Usopp did not create another "magic" weapon for himself? He can make one for himself, right? I know he has [Pop Green](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Pop_Green) which he uses frequently, but it's more of an ammunition for him than a weapon. Why doesn't he create some weapons for himself?

Comment: His Kabuto is a super powered slignshot that shoots farther and more acurately than firearms. So he DID make one such weapon for himself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He does.

Not only does Usopp have hammers (which are quite modest), but he uses a variety of gadgets to help him though most are ineffective and funny. He uses Caltrops, fingernails on chalkboard, grapling hooks, suction cup shoes, and fireworks. He also uses several dials from Skypeia but these are few and far between.

The more impressive weapons are his slingshots.  He has had three.  The first seems to just be a normal slingshot but he made the latter two and they are amazing. Kabuto uses dials to accelerate the shot fast enough to snipe targets a long distance away. Kuro Kabuto is actually a living more dynamic version of Kabuto.

Finally, Usopp's lies are his main weapon but that is not really relevant to this question.

The impressive thing about Nami's Clima Tact is the part Usopp can't replicate. It originally contained a series of gimmicks and tricks that seem to make sense as the kind of silly thing Usopp would make for himself. Nami was able to use that in very unexpected ways with her weather knowledge and amazing intelligence (third highest in the history of the East Blue which is about 1/5th of the entire world).  Later versions of the Clima Tact have more of her input so are less silly.  They depend on her weather and scientific knowledge which Usopp simply doesn't have.

Comment: I'm completely forgot about dials xD so, about the Clima Tact, Usopp never expected that the Clima Tact could be so powerful even he also made about cool ball, heat ball, and thunder ball?

Comment: hahaha agreed `Finally, Ussop's lies are his main weapon` LoL